# 10 fold cross validation with sample size that is not a factor of 10

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I see papers that use 10-fold cross validation on data sets that have a number of samples indivisible by 10.

I couldn't find any case where they explained how they chose each subset.

My assumption is that they use resampling to some extent, but if this were to be the case then a sample could appear in both subsets and therefore bias the model.

Paper as example: http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/9/319

Would it be recommended to do the following;

- Given a sample size of 86 take 8 samples as a holdout set.
- Use the remaining samples to train.
- repeat 10 times.

Doing it this way would have it so every sample is a training set but only 80/86 samples are used as holdouts and there is no bias of having it occur within both a training and holdout set.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the folds to have equal size, or as close to equal as possible.

To do this, if you have `86` samples and want to use 10 fold CV, then the first `86 % 10 = 6` folds will have size `86 / 10 + 1 = 9` and the rest will have size `86 / 10 = 8`:

```
6 * 9 = 54
4 * 8 = 32   +
--------------
86
```

In general, if you have `n` samples and `n_folds` folds, you want to do what [scikit-learn does](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html):

> The first n % n_folds folds have size n // n_folds + 1, other folds have size n // n_folds.

Note: `//` stands for integer division

I'm not aware of a proper scientific reference for this, but it seems to be the convention. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134266/does-k-fold-cross-validation-always-imply-k-uniformly-sized-subsets) and also [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43876/partitioning-data-for-k-fold-cross-validation-that-will-not-have-equal-partition) for the same suggestions. At least two major machine learning libraries do it this way.

Comment: this seems to make a lot more sense than my suggestion, thanks.